# pass additional properties to router meta field value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating an admin dashboard with Vuetify which is protected via authentication. Basically I need multiple layouts because my login view doesn't need the toolbar, sidebar, etc.

I created a **PublicCenteredLayout** for my Login component

```
<template>
  <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="4">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

and add a meta tag field to my login route

```
{
  path: "/login",
  component: Login,
  meta: { layout: PublicCenteredLayout }
}
```

and with the help of dynamic components I render the correct layout via `$route.meta.layout`. As you can see the layout used predefined columns `<v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="4">` I would like to know if there is a way I can pass those information to the layout field as additional values. The pseudo code would be

`meta: { layout: PublicCenteredLayout { sm:8, md:4 } }`

but this is invalid syntax. The only solution I could think of would be

```
meta: {
  layoutInfo: {
    component: PublicCenteredLayout
    // additional fields here
  }
}
```

so I could access those fields via `$route.meta.layoutInfo.sm`. This solution might not be the best one because JavaScript provides this value even if it doesn't exist. With Vue 3 I would like to switch to TypeScript and then I might run into some errors.

Any better ideas for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript provides this value even if it doesn't exist"? I think your proposed solution is good.

Comment: I mean that I can access object keys even if they don't exist. With TypeScript I might not be able to do that because it knows which class members exist and which don't

Comment: Is that your main concern – typescript compatibility? In typescript you can designate optional fields. But also, I would imagine that the `meta` property would have the `any` type anyway to allow for any user type (I can't see how you would strongly-type it anyway).

Comment: well yes, if this is of type `any` it should be fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this...
src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <component :is="layout">
      <router-view :layout.sync="layout" />
    </component>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    layout: "div"
  })
};
</script>
```

And then in the view pages i import the template i want to use and pass that along....
This .vue view page uses the basic.vue layout

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Basic from "../layouts/basic.vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "About",
  created() {
    this.$emit("update:layout", Basic);
  }
});
</script>
```

And this one, a differnt template

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <h1>This is my dashboard page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Fancy from "../layouts/fancy-with-menu.vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Dashboard",
  created() {
    this.$emit("update:layout", Fancy);
  }
});
</script>
```